# Автівка чи автомобіль?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Досить часто у новинах можна почути чи побачити слово "*автівка*". Також є приклади використання в художній літературі: "Ти приречений заходити, ніби у воду, в порожні вересневі провулки, де листя засипає *автівки* й з вікон на вулицю викидають старі меблі" (С. Жадан. Вогнепальні й ножові).

У [вільному тлумачному словнику](http://sum.in.ua/f/avtivka) знайшла це слово:

*авті́вка,* -и, жін.
Те саме, що автомобіль.
Підійшли до машини. Сєва підійняв капот, розглядаючи ум'ятини. Тамара сіла до автівки. Я теж упав на своє місце (Сергій Жадан, Ворошиловград, 2010);
Батько не вірить у випадковість його [Чорновола] загибелі — у пустелях тієї ночі, на безлюдній дорозі, коли КАМАЗ із причепом зненацька розвернувся впоперек траси, і автівка на повній швидкості врізалася в той причеп… Ніхто не вірить   (Ліна Костенко, Записки українського самашедшого, 2010).

Але в СУМ-20 цього слова нема. Чи правильно вживати *"автівка"* замість "*авто*" чи "*автомобіль*" в офіційно-діловому стилі?

Comment: "Доцільно" - залежить від ваших цілей. Як бачите у художній літературі вживається. Інше питання - чи можна вживати у офіційних текстах і т.і.

Comment: так, саме це я мала на увазі, чи можна вживати в офіційних текстах?

Comment: [Державні сайти](//www.google.com/search?q=автіка+site:gov.ua), зокрема [Прикордонна служба](//www.google.com/search?q=автіка+site:dpsu.gov.ua), іноді вживають.

Comment: На мою думку, це як «наразі» — хоч словники ще не фіксують як повністю нормативне, але по факту вже вживається, навіть, здається, в офіційній мові.

Answer (score 2):

АВТІВКА має  всі шанси в майбутньому засвоїтися в різних стилях, але зараз це слово поширене лише в усному мовленні, літературі й публіцистиці, в інтернеті, новинах. В офіційних документах не може використовуватися слово із виразним розмовним забарвленням, так само, до речі, як і слово АВТО. Офіційно-ділова мова має обрати серед синонімів варіант АВТОМОБІЛЬ.

> АВТО, невідм., сер., ***розм***. Те саме, що автомобіль.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/avto)

> ...мовні засоби великою мірою ***стандартизовані***,  слова вживаються в
>   прямому значенні, ***обмежена синонімія***...

[mova.info](http://www.mova.info/pidruchn.aspx?l1=102)